# Recovering lost Amazon RDS master user login details

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

The method specified [in this tutorial](http://jonsimpson.co.uk/log/2011/lost-rds-master-user-login) does not seem to work for me.

When I run `rds-describe-db-instances` with correct region, it says:

> improperly formatted command

Any thoughts on how to recover the user login details?

Comment: Have you installed the AWS command line tools?

Comment: Yes I have!. I am also able to run `rds-describe-db-instances --help`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the aws cli tools:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier <db name> | grep Master
```